# Recup hidden_field_tag value in params controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, hidden-field

I create an hidden_field_tag name chunk for take in params the number of chunk and after do what i want. But after create the hidden_field_tag I cant take the params. My hidden_field is a variable not create in my database or in my model.

The form :

```
<%= form_for Sound.new , :html => { :multipart => true, :id => "fileupload", :style => 'margin: 0;'} do |f| %>
<%= f.file_field :file, multiple: true, id: 'upload-field'%>
<%= hidden_field_tag "chunk", "0" %>
<%= f.submit %>
```

By default the value is 0 but I increase this value in js.

JS

```
 chunk++;
 $('#chunk').val(chunk);
```

That work but in my controller if I puts params[:chunk].inspect , the answer is nil.
And I didn't see in my parameters the chunk variable.

My controller

```
 def create
    @sound = Sound.new(params[:sound])
    @sound.title = params[:title].to_s.gsub(/\[|\]|"/,'')
    @sound.user_id = current_user.id
    puts params.inspect
    puts params[:chunk].inspect
```

Anyone can help me ? 
Thank's

Comment: It is very unlikely what you are saying; it should be present. Check the server log and see if the request params include chunk; if they don't, I would consider that some JS is doing something weird

Comment: The request params doesn't include chunk

Comment: Check if the HTML include `<input type="hidden" name="chunk" value="0"/>`: if it doesn't, it is a `hidden_field_tag` problem; otherwise, probably is javascript

Comment: When I inspect the element : <input id="chunk" name="chunk" type="hidden" value="3">. I set the value="3" in my javascript.

Comment: In my case, the name of the hidden_param blocked me.  Try renaming your param to "my_chunk" and see if it shows up in the params-hash.  Rails adds more "cannot use this" hurdles with each release, so what worked before may break after an 'upgrade'.